# Why TCP accepted socket does not need bind(int, __CONST_SOCKADDR_ARG, socklen_t)

Tags: sockets, tcp

Is the child socket created after

```
int accept(__fd, __SOCKADDR_ARG __addr, socklen_t *__restrict __addr_len)
```

bound to a local address, if not why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is bound to a local IP/port.  It is bound to the specific local IP that accepted the connection request (especially if the listening socket is bound to multiple local IPs via a wildcard IP, like `INADDR_ANY`), and to the same local port that the listening socket is bound to.

Comment: Actually I believe it is bound to the target IP address of the SYN packet, which isn't necessarily the same as the IP that accepted the connection request, due to the 'weak end system model'.